# Nullable return type not working in Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

Given this code

```
export interface ICollectionService {
  get(id: string): Promise<Collection | null>;
}

const collection = await collectionService.get(collectionAddress);
```

Now my `collection` variable showing in the IDE is `Collection` type
Not `Collection | null` as I expected.

Not sure if this has something to do with the eslint?

Here is my `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'],
  overrides: [],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {}
};
```

Comment: What's your tsconfig? If you're not in strict mode every type is nullable, so `Collection | null` is the same thing as `Collection`.

Comment: Add  "strictNullChecks": true to the compilerOptions in tsconfig/eslintric.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks you guys, It's the "strictNullChecks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `compilerOptions.strictNullChecks` flag in the `tsconfig.json` to `true`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

The default value of `compilerOptions.strictNullChecks` is `false`

Comment: Tadaa.. It's work.